# Finding the highest number of consecutive "a" in a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, count, find, append

Say that the user inputs: daslakndlaaaaajnjndibniaaafijdnfijdnsijfnsdinifaaaaaaaaaaafnnasm. How would you go about finding the highest number of consecutive "a" and how would you remove the "a"'s and leave only 2 of them instead of the large number of them before. Thanks !
I was thinking to append each letter into an empty list but not sure if that's right or how to go from there. I'm kind of stuck, don't really know what direction to go to solve this one.
I've asked this question 20 minutes ago but got flagged for not giving enough info and a bad title.
Support ant tips would be much appreciated.

Comment: I did edit the last one but it's still on hold.

Comment: Yes. You didn't address the problem one of the comments brought up, which is that you haven't made an attempt to solve the problem yourself, or at least haven't posted one.

Comment: I've mentioned that I don't know where to start on this one. Perhaps appending each letter to a new list ?

Answer (score 0):

```
print len(max(re.findall("a+","daslakndlaaaaajnjndibniaaafijdnfijdnsijfnsdinifaaaaaaaaaaafnnasm"),key=len))

print re.sub("aa+","aa","daslakndlaaaaajnjndibniaaafijdnfijdnsijfnsdinifaaaaaaaaaaafnnasm")
```